# syntax for ancestor:: in Xpath expression

Tags: xml, xpath

`xpath -e '//attribute::vo/../text()' books.xml`

returns the content of each element having an attribute named `vo`.

For example, with this `book.xml` :

```
<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en" vo="it">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="children">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web">
  <title lang="en" vo="fr">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

then the request :

`xpath -e '//attribute::vo/../text()' books.xml`

gives :

```
Found 2 nodes in /tmp/books.xml:
-- NODE --
Everyday Italian
-- NODE --
XQuery Kick Start
```

What should be the syntax of the request having the same result, but with `ancestor::` in place of `..` ?

Comment: what should be your output.

Comment: ```
Found 2 nodes in /tmp/books.xml:
-- NODE --
Everyday Italian
-- NODE --
XQuery Kick Start
```

Comment: Wouldn't `//title[@vo]/text()` be much simpler?

Comment: This `//*[@vo]/text()` is less convoluted than `//attribute::vo/../text()`. You want to select the same text nodes but using `ancestor` axis. As I show you, many expression exist selecting the same with different path (you have used `..`, the abbreviated form of `parent` axis, I don't)

Answer (score 1):

I understand that `//attribute::vo/../text()` is not an natural Xpath expression.

`//*[@vo]/text()` is better.

So no need to introduce `ancestor::` or `parent::` in place of `..`.

Comment: Certainly the `//attribute::vo/../text()` formulation seems very strange and non-idiomatic but you have to be careful about saying it's "not optimal" - you would have to justify that by explaining what metric you are using to assess it.

Comment: I've replaced optimal with natural. Is it better ?

Comment: Yes, "natural" is better, because it makes clear that it's an entirely subjective judgement.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to know how `ancestor` works, it takes parent of current node, grand parent of current node and so on up to the root. So your query with `ancestor` would look like

```
//attribute::vo/ancestor::*[1]/title/text()
```

Where `ancestor` means that you're going to collect all the (grand)parents, `*` means that you do not care of what nodes those (grand)parents would be, and `[1]` means that you need the "closest" one to the current node.

The same result would be produced by the following query:

```
//attribute::vo/ancestor::book/title/text()
```

Since it doesn't take root element because it is not `book` node. So that we have "flat" hierarchy here.

The following query would take only the books with "Web" category (this is not what you asked actually but probably will give more clear vision on how to work with axes):

`//attribute::vo/ancestor::book[@category='web']/title/text()`